# Injective function and compact set

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M\to N$ be a differentiable function between smooth manifolds. Let $K\subset M$ be a compact set and $f$ is injective on $K$. Also $Df$ is an isomorphism on $K$. Show that there exists an open set $U$ containing $K$ such that $f$ is injective on $U$.

Thanks in advance.